# Adding a foreign key to database - how does it change my application?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, foreign-keys

I have made a working application that shows contacts from database, allows editing and deleting them and each of their emails/telephones/tags.

Database looks like this:

```
Contacts - Id (P), Name, Surname, Address;
Emails - EntryId (P), PersonId, Email1;
Telephones - EntryId (P), PersonId, Telephone1;
Tags - EntryId (P), PersonId, Tag1;
```

(where P means primary key and PersonId is always the corresponding Id from Contacts table, of the person whose email that is)

I haven't connected my tables in any way, I just approched Email of a person with id ID like this, for example:

```
var mailsById = contactsData.Emails.Where(x => x.PersonId == ID).ToList();
```

Now I realized I should maybe add a foreign key to tables Emails, Telephones, Tags, which would be the PersonId connected to Id from table Contacts. So I added this to table definitons on Emails:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_Emails_Contacts] FOREIGN KEY ([PersonId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Contacts] ([Id])
```

(same with Telephones and Tags)

Everything went well, in the EDMX diagram it now shows (1,*) connections between Contacts table and every other table (which I wanted), but now I get an *500 (Internal Server Error)* on the following function. Function returns complete info about all the contacts in the database (on the frontend, I have a table Name-Surname-Address-Emails-Telephones-Tags, that's why I'm connecting all the tables from database to one list).

```
public JsonResult getAll()
    {
        using (ContactsDBEntities contactsData = new ContactsDBEntities())
        {
            List<Contact_Info> completeList = new List<Contact_Info>();
            var contacts = contactsData.Contacts;
            var emails = contactsData.Emails;
            var telephones = contactsData.Telephones;
            var tags = contactsData.Tags;

            //GroupJoin:
            //Outer.GroupJoin(Inner, outer => key, inner => key, (outer, inner) => result)

            //first join joins contacts table with emails table
            var contactList = contacts.GroupJoin(emails,
                contact => contact.Id,
                email => email.PersonId,
                (contact, email) => new
                {
                    Id = contact.Id,
                    Name = contact.Name,
                    Surname = contact.Surname,
                    Address = contact.Address,
                    Email = email
                });

            //second join joins telephones to the existing contacts-emails list
            var contactList2 = contactList.GroupJoin(telephones,
                contact => contact.Id,
                telephone => telephone.PersonId,
                (contact, telephone) => new
                {
                    Id = contact.Id,
                    Name = contact.Name,
                    Surname = contact.Surname,
                    Address = contact.Address,
                    Email = contact.Email,
                    Telephone = telephone
                });

            //third join creates the needed contacts-emails-telephones-tags list
            var contactList3 = contactList2.GroupJoin(tags,
                contact => contact.Id,
                tag => tag.PersonId,
                (contact, tag) => new
                {
                    Id = contact.Id,
                    Name = contact.Name,
                    Surname = contact.Surname,
                    Address = contact.Address,
                    Email = contact.Email,
                    Telephone = contact.Telephone,
                    Tag = tag
                });

            //contactList3 to completeList
            foreach(var contact in contactList3)
            {
                Contact_Info temp = new Contact_Info();
                temp.Id = contact.Id;
                temp.Name = contact.Name;
                temp.Surname = contact.Surname;
                temp.Address = contact.Address;
                foreach (var em in contact.Email)
                {
                    temp.Emails.Add(em);
                }
                foreach (var tel in contact.Telephone)
                {
                    temp.Telephones.Add(tel);
                }
                foreach (var tag in contact.Tag)
                {
                    temp.Tags.Add(tag);
                }
                completeList.Add(temp);
            }

            return Json(completeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                
        }
    }
```

This is my Contact_Info class which is used in this function:

```
public class Contact_Info
    {
        public Contact_Info () {}

        public Contact_Info (string name, string surname, string address, List<Email> emails, List<Telephone> telephones, List<Tag> tags)
        {
            Name = name;
            Surname = surname;
            Address = address;
            Emails = emails;
            Telephones = telephones;
            Tags = tags;
        }

        public int Id;
        public string Name;
        public string Surname;
        public string Address;
        public List<Email> Emails = new List<Email>();
        public List<Telephone> Telephones = new List<Telephone>();
        public List<Tag> Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }
```

I tried debugging server side code, it returns no exeptions :/ This is the error output: *The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.*

Can you maybe tell me what I need to change in the working application if I changed this foreign-key properties of tables? Is it too late to be doing it now (i.e. does it require changing my code radically), and how important are the foreign key constraints here? This is my first use of databases in a more complex code, so please have understanding if I made some please-don't-do-that mistakes :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: At which line do you get that error about The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Hm, I can't find it, is it possible that it isn't stated on which line the error occurs?

Comment: When you are debugging, do you get the error before the action method is ended or after?

Answer (score 0):

If navigation properties exist between your entities (ie. you generated the edmx from the database and FK constraints exist), then you don't need to get the entities individually and then join them. Just use Include():

```
var contacts = contactsData.Contacts
      .Include(x=>x.Emails)
      .Include(x=>x.Telephones)
      .Include(x=>x.Tags)
      .ToList();
```

I think Include is part of the System.Data.Entity namespace.

Comment: I added the System.Data.Entity namespace and rewrote my getAll() function, so now it looks like this:

`public JsonResult getAll()
        {
            using (ContactsDBEntities contactsData = new ContactsDBEntities())
            {
                var contacts = contactsData.Contacts
                  .Include(x => x.Emails)
                  .Include(x => x.Telephones)
                  .Include(x => x.Tags)
                  .ToList();
                return Json(contacts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }`

Comment: It still returns an error, this time the output is: _A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Contact_55F0F20179BF8BAB1AC8CFFF6A7F318746B8C25429864C6FAE931BBF884EB6E3'._

Comment: So you are getting the data and serializing, but the parent has a reference to the child and the child has a reference to the parent. So when it serializes there is an endless circular reference. What you need to do is go to each child model and add [JsonIgnore] attribute to the navigational property pointing to the parent. That attribute is in the newtonsoft namespace. This will let the serializer know that it doesn't need to serialize the parent again in the child model. If you regenerate your models from the Database, you will need to add the attribute again.